# Stacking up methods in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have an object I created with this snip-it that looks like this:

```
  ...
  var steps = new Array();
  this.createStep = function(){steps.push(new step()); return steps[steps.length-1];}; 
  this.getSteps = function(){return steps;}; //returns Array
  this.removeStep = function(pos){steps.splice(parseInt(pos), 1);}; // integer possition zero base
  this.insertStep = function(pos){steps.splice(parseInt(pos),0, new step());};
```

And this works fine:

```
...
var newStep = wfObj.createStep();
newStep.setTitle('Step-'+i);
newStep.setStatus('New');
```

but this does not

```
var newStep = wfObj.createStep().setTitle('Step-'+i).setStatus('New');
```

Could someone please tell me how to fix this or even what to call it when you chain methods like this?

Comment: Your setters would need to return the object.

Comment: @DaveNewton: Why don't you write that as an answer?

Comment: @NedBatchelder Too short; not worth it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [Ned said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7549024/x/7549031#7549031), this is sometimes called [fluent interface](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Fluent_interface). It's also sometimes called [method chaining](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Method_chaining), as you have heard.

You probably have some code somewhere that looks like this:

```
this.setTitle = function(newTitle) {
    title = newTitle;
};
```

Change that to this:

```
this.setTitle = function(newTitle) {
    title = newTitle;
    return this;
};
```

Do the same for `setStatus`.

Comment: Thank you everyone you're the best! Sometimes knowing what to call it can make all the difference.

Answer (score 6):

This is called a fluent interface.  The way to make it work is to have every function return `this`.